# Convert or rearrange php array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I want to convert or rearrange this php array :

```
$contacts = array(
array(
    "name" => "Peter Parker",
    "email" => "peterparker@mail.com",
),
array(
    "name" => "Peter Parker", 
    "email" => "petermail2@mail.com",
),
array(
    "name" => "Harry Potter",
    "email" => "harrypotter@mail.com",
)
);
```

to :

```
 $contacts ["Peter Parker"] = {"peterparker@mail.com", "petermail2@mail.com"  } ;
 $contacts ["Harry Potter"] = {"harrypotter@mail.com"} ;
```

that means assembling or merge entries with same name in a new array or row.

Comment: ok, so start codeing

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: We are not a code writing service! Start to work on something before posting here

Comment: try with array_reduce where the element u pass is the resulting array u want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach( $contacts as $record ){
    $newcontacts[$record['name']][] = $record['email'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
foreach ($contacts as $name => $email){
    $merged[$name][] = $email;
}
```